# ajax link not working though jquery is loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a link to in my view

```
= link_to "Remove from Handy List", {controller: "handy_lists", action: "destroy_via_ajax", tradie_id: "1"}, method: :get, remote: true, class: "pull-right"
```

In my routes I have

```
get "handy_lists/destroy_via_ajax/:tradie_id", to: "handy_lists#destroy_via_ajax"
```

The action for now simply displays

```
def destroy_via_ajax
  puts "it deletes"
end
```

Whenever I click the button the server isn't responding. I've checked and javascript and jquery are loaded so I know it can't be that. I don't know what I'm missing. What's wrong with the link and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things which could be wrong:

**Is your remote link working?**

This would be the first thing to test. I would use the development console in either [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) or [Mozilla](http://getfirebug.com/) & click on the "network" tab, to see if the link is actually requesting some sort of ajax link.

Likelihood is that it is, but I don't think you've set up your system correctly

---

**Your controller setup could be incorrect**

You're calling the action "`destroy with ajax`"... why not just use the [`respond_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) function in the normal destroy action?

You could try this:

```
def destroy
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

This will allow you to create `destroy.js.erb` in your `views/controller` folder, where you can then call something like:

```
alert('Deleted Successfully!');
```

This should work, but I am open to chat if you need more help!

Comment: Although I found out the error was caused by something else altogether, you did a great job at breaking things down for me.

Comment: No problem sir! What was the problem in the end? It would be great to see what the issue was

Comment: I was blanking out the href attribute via jquery before the ajax call was called. It was a mistake on my part but I fixed it.